# SQLAlchemy - How to Filter Properties of Related Classes During Query Without Class Reference?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I struggled with the title for this question so let me just lay out the code:

File A:

```
class SomeClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some_classes'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    my_awesome_property = Column(Unicode(255))
    other_class = relationship('OtherClass', backref='some_class', uselist=False)
```

File B:

```
class OtherClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'other_classes'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    my_sweet_property = Column(Unicode(255))
    some_class_id = Column(ForeignKey('some_classes.id'))
```

Now, in many cases I would refer to both of these files from a "higher-order" file containing some functions like so:

Higher Order File:

```
from model.alpha import SomeClass
from model.bravo import OtherClass
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

session = sessionmaker(bind=some_engine)()

def some_random_query():
    return session.query(SomeClass).join(OtherClass).filter(OtherClass.my_sweet_property=='Mike Bayer\'s cat speaks SQL.').first()
```

So that's pretty normal, nothing wrong with that... until... I decide I want to a put a function into one of the lower-level files like File A (and avoid circular imports)

Back to File A:

```
# pretend I imported a session here
def frustrating_situation():
     session.query(SomeClass).join(SomeClass.other_class).filter(SomeClass.other_class.my_sweet_property=='Get ready for an exception!').first()
```

This will throw this bad boy right here:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with SomeClass.other_class has an attribute 'my_sweet_property'
```

Now I suppose that makes sense given what I know of the internals of SQLAlchemy, but I also think from an API standpoint that statement should really work.

Here is how I worked around it:

```
session.query(SomeClass).join(SomeClass.other_class).filter(SomeClass.other_class.property.mapper.c.my_sweet_property == 'verbose, yet it works as desired').first()
```

**So after all that, my question is really quite simple: Does anybody know a better / more idiomatic / proper / less dirty feeling way of doing this?**

Suggestions welcome.

*Side Note*

For anyone who is wondering:

**"Why not just import the class you want the reference to for the join/filter operation?"**

There are a couple reasons why you might not want to / be able to import the class into the module where you are writing the query.

- You have split up your class definitions across many files and decided to avoid circular imports by strictly not importing across same-level modules
- You have decided to place functions that operate on 1 or more classes not currently defined or imported in the current module and do not wish to import them because they are not used for any other reason in the module (and see reason 1 again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SomeClass.other_class.my_sweet_property
```

doesn't work in sqlalchemy.  sorry.

You are referring to `OtherClass`, in this `.filter()` clause.  how you arrive at that name is your business, but the clearest way, from the point of view of what each statement means and where the arguments come from is still just to import things.

*edit:*  A common cause of problems with circular imports occurs when you try to import the names out of modules directly instead of just importing the modules.  If you turn code that looks like:

```
from foo import Bar
def baz():
    Bar.quux()
```

you'll have an import problem if foo is also trying to import this module (say, because it wants to use baz).

Fix it by importing only the module:

```
import foo
def baz()
    foo.Bar.quux()
```

since `foo.Bar` is resolved later, only when `baz()` is called, you don't have any trouble when this module gets *imported*, since it doesn't actually try to use the contents of any of the modules it imports.

Comment: Right-- so I know that doesn't work as mentioned in my question. What I am wondering is if there is a pattern in SQLAlchemy for class referencing across files (for filter), very similiar to how you can do string based primaryjoin etc... to allow for the references to be worked out on the fly when the query actually runs.

Comment: Neat trick regarding lambda I'm gonna use that ty :)

Basically the premise for my question is that I am paranoid about circular imports and unecessary namespace cluttering. What I like to do, is keep all of the model definitions (along with functions that pertain at a lower level like you said to their operation) in modules which I consider same-level (meaning I will strictly never import across them). Then I'll use a higher level module which will draw on any and all of those module definitions, to compose the higher level functionality. So I think yes, you understand where I am coming from.

Comment: I am aware of that distinction, I think my approach stems more from wanting a really clear namespace and high/low level functionality boundary. Take this example:

Module Structure:
model/
model/__init__
model/apple
model/orange

Inside of the apple module I would have a function like get_by_weight() or get_orange_weight_intersection(oranges)

But in the __init__, I would likely have something like:

def load_trucks(max_weight):
    trucks.find_available()
    apple.get_by_weight(max_weight)
    oranges.some_function()

Comment: if they are the "same level" then they obviously cannot use each other without circular imports.  see if you can separate the "models" from the "functions that use them", with models being at a separate, lower level.

Comment: Yes, so I used to do it that way, but I favor the functional style and I pretty much treat class objects as immutable data objects to be stored and retreived and used to generate more data. So what I end up with is a lot of functions in one place "above" the models and then a bunch of models "below". I was hoping for some happy marriage of the two where a module could contain logical groupings of functions and models that those functions use frequently.
Thanks a lot btw for your input, I realize this is more of a stylistic question anyways :)

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer if nobody else weighs in by tomorrow, I was secretly hoping Mike Bayer would notice the question and tell me about some secret SQLAlchemy technique for accessing properties through Mapper objects :)